# How to Set packageNameSuffix per build variant in Android Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Our application has a free and a paid version. We also make branded-versions, which means that the application vary in two dimensions.

Four versions could be:

- The App, Nike ed. free
- The APP, Nike ed. paid
- The App, Adidas ed.  paid
- The App, Adidas ed. free

My solution now is to have two build-types, paid and free:

```
  buildTypes {
        paid {
            packageNameSuffix ".paid"
        }

        free {
            packageNameSuffix ".free"
        }
    }
```

And two build flavors:

```
productFlavors{
    nike{
        packageName "com.example.theapp.nike"
    }

    adidas{
        packageName "com.example.theapp.adidas"
    }

}
```

For leagacy reasons one of our app variants does not have the free-suffix, but is still to be handled as a free version. What I want is to be able to get hold of the build flavor when setting the packageNameSuffix in the builtTypes-block. In pseudo-code I would want something like this:

```
 buildTypes {
        free {
            if( buildFlavor != "nike"){
                packageNameSuffix ".free"
            }
        }
    }
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. You can use this by creating 4 projects and each project having a Package  with single class file which shows that it is free/paid version of App1/App2 and a Library Project having content of all 4 applications.

Comment: Yes its possible with single project as well.

Comment: First create a library Project and mark it as library project by navigating to Properties of the project. Then create another project and right click on that project -> Properties -> Android ->Scroll Down and click Add -> Then the library project will be displayed. Select that and run the latest one(not library project)